Consumer for type's messages "RoutingSlipActivityCompleted"
I've a code in which a routing slip is built. A consumer for consuming the completion of each routing slip's activity is built too but this part is never reached.
This is the part in which the routing slip is built:
public class UpsertCredentialConsumer : IConsumer<IUpsertCredentialRequest>, IConsumer<RoutingSlipCompleted>, IConsumer<RoutingSlipFaulted>
{
    private readonly ILogger<UpsertCredentialConsumer> _logger;

    public UpsertCredentialConsumer(ILogger<UpsertCredentialConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IUpsertCredentialRequest> context)
    {
        var routingSlip = CreateRoutingSlip(context);

        await context.Execute(routingSlip);
    }

    private RoutingSlip CreateRoutingSlip(ConsumeContext<IUpsertCredentialRequest> context)
    {
        var builder = new RoutingSlipBuilder(NewId.NextGuid());

        builder.SetVariables(new
        {
            context.RequestId,
            context.ResponseAddress
        });

        foreach(var cred in context.Message.AgdtCredential)
        {
            //Se credential non presente
            if (cred.AsIsCredential is null)
            {
                //InsertCredential
                AddInsertCredentialActivity(builder, context.Message, cred.Credential);

                //InsertExternalRefeCredential
                builder.AddActivity(XXX.Name, XXX.Queue,
                new
                {
                 ...
                });
            }

            //Se credential presente
            if (cred.AsIsCredential is not null)
            {
                //UpdateCredential
                AddUpdateCredentialActivity(builder, context.Message, cred.Credential, cred.AsIsCredential);

                if (!cred.Credential.Status.Equals(cred.AsIsCredential.Status))
                {
                    //SetCredentialStatus se lo stato da settare è diverso da quello esistente
                    builder.AddActivity(YYY.Name, YYY.Queue,
                    new
                    {
                     ...
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //SetCredentialStatus
                builder.AddActivity(YYY.Name, YYY.Queue,
                new
                {
                 ...
                });
            }
        }

        builder.AddSubscription(context.ReceiveContext.InputAddress, RoutingSlipEvents.Completed & RoutingSlipEvents.Faulted & RoutingSlipEvents.ActivityCompleted);

        return builder.Build();
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipCompleted> context)
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("(IUpsertCredentialRequest) Routing Slip Completed: {TrackingNumber}", context.Message.TrackingNumber);

        var requestId = context.GetVariable<Guid>("RequestId");
        var responseAddress = context.GetVariable<Uri>("ResponseAddress");

        var responseEndpoint = await context.GetSendEndpoint(responseAddress);

        await responseEndpoint.Send<IUpsertCredentialResult>(
            new
            {
                Success = true,
                __RequestId = requestId,
                Data = context.Message.Variables["credentialId"]
            });
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipFaulted> context)
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("(IUpsertCredentialRequest) Routing Slip Faulted: {TrackingNumber} {ExceptionInfo}",
                                            context.Message.TrackingNumber,
                                            context.Message.ActivityExceptions.FirstOrDefault());

        var requestId = context.GetVariable<Guid>("RequestId");
        var responseAddress = context.GetVariable<Uri>("ResponseAddress");

        if (requestId.HasValue && responseAddress != null)
        {
            var responseEndpoint = await context.GetSendEndpoint(responseAddress);

            var validationError = context.Message.Variables.TryGetValue("ErrorCode", out object errorValidation);

            var exceptions = context.Message.ActivityExceptions.Select(x => x.ExceptionInfo);

            var errorCode = errorValidation is null ? exceptions.Select(x => x.Message).FirstOrDefault()
                                                    : ScsExceptions.ScsValidationError.ToString();

            _logger.LogTrace("{TrackingNumber} ErrorCode: {error}", context.Message.TrackingNumber, errorCode);

            await responseEndpoint.Send<IUpsertCredentialResult>(
                    new
                    {
                        Success = false,
                        ErrorCode = errorCode,
                        __RequestId = requestId
                    });
        }
    }

And this is the consumer of RoutingSlipActivityCompleted message:
public class RoutingSlipEventConsumer : IConsumer<RoutingSlipActivityCompleted>, IConsumer<RoutingSlipFaulted>
{
    private readonly ILogger<RoutingSlipEventConsumer> _logger;

    public RoutingSlipEventConsumer(ILogger<RoutingSlipEventConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipActivityCompleted> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Routing Slip Activity Completed: {TrackingNumber} {ActivityName}",
                                           context.Message.TrackingNumber,
                                           context.Message.ActivityName);
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RoutingSlipFaulted> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Routing Slip Faulted: {TrackingNumber} {ExceptionInfo}",
                                           context.Message.TrackingNumber,
                                           context.Message.ActivityExceptions.FirstOrDefault());

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

For precision, this is also the code's part in which the consumer are registered:
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<allTheOtherConsumer>().Endpoint(x=> x.Temporary = true);
    x.AddConsumer<RoutingSlipEventConsumer>().Endpoint(x => x.Temporary = true);

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    { 
        cfg.Host(...);

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

I'm expecting that the RoutingSlipEventConsumer take the message RoutingSlipActivityCompleted and write the linked informations in the log's file, but it's never happened

You need to use the proper binary operator.
builder.AddSubscription(context.ReceiveContext.InputAddress,
  RoutingSlipEvents.Completed | 
  RoutingSlipEvents.Faulted | 
  RoutingSlipEvents.ActivityCompleted);

Also, your subscription address isn't correct, so those messages are likely going into the _skipped queue. But since your queue is temporary, it's likely all being deleted when you stop the application. That, or your UpsertCredentialConsumer needs to consume the activity completed event.

Yeah, you're right. I've tried both binary operator and in this question is showed the last that I used. Unfortunately also if I used | operator the problem isn't solved

Okay so if change my queue to not temporary, should it work? I register now my consumers like this:
x.AddConsumer();
x.AddConsumer();
x.AddConsumer();
x.AddConsumer();
x.AddConsumer();

As I stated in the answer, your subscription address appears to be going to the wrong consumer, or you need to add an additional subscription for the other consumer's endpoint.
